# How to specify type for no-content response for Axios in ReactQuery useMutate using TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-query

I've been trying to get familiar with ReactQuery and TypeScript lately and based on the signature for `useMutation`:

`function useMutation<TData = unknown, TError = unknown, TVariables = void, TContext = unknown>`

The way I understand this, is the following:

- `TData` is the type for the result returned when calling `mutate`.
- `TError` is the type for the error response in case of error.
- `TVariables` is the type for the arguments being passed to `mutate`

I'm currently trying to create a hook that will post to an endpoint which, in case of success, will return a 204 No Content response, so I tried this:

```js
const { mutate, ...actionResults } = useMutation<
    AxiosResponse<null>, // <-- I put null here because I expect a 204 no content response
    AxiosError<ErrorResponseType>,
    ParamsInterface
  >(
    ({param1, param2}: ParamsInterface) => { // Having null above gives me an error on this line, see details below.
      return requestor(Rest.sendRequest(param1, param2))
    },
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        // do something on success
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        // do something on error
      },
    },
  )
```

The error mentioned in the comment above is:

```
Overload 1 of 4, '(mutationFn: MutationFunction<AxiosResponse<null>, ParamsInterface>, options?: Omit<UseMutationOptions<AxiosResponse<null>, AxiosError<ErrorResponseType>, ParamsInterface, unknown>, "mutationFn">): UseMutationResult<...>', gave the following error.
     Argument of type '({ param1, param2 }: ParamsInterface) => AxiosPromise<object>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MutationFunction<AxiosResponse<null>, ParamsInterface>'.
       Call signature return types 'AxiosPromise<object>' and 'Promise<AxiosResponse<null>>' are incompatible.
         The types of 'then' are incompatible between these types.
           Type '<TResult1 = AxiosResponse<object>, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: AxiosResponse<object>) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = AxiosResponse<null>, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: AxiosResponse<null>) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) => Promise<...>'.
             Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
               Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
                 Type 'AxiosResponse<object>' is not assignable to type 'AxiosResponse<null>'.
                   Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'null'.
```

The above error goes away by leaving `AxiosResponse` untyped, which I assume leaves it with the default `any` type.

Why is the type defined in the response (`TData`) affecting the type expected in the params for `mutate` (`TVariables`)? At least that's how I see it at the moment, maybe I don't understand the error message correctly.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please don't "pass generics" to `useMutation`. Just type your `mutationFn` and let the rest be inferred:

```
const { mutate, ...actionResults } = useMutation(
    ({param1, param2}: ParamsInterface): Promise<AxiosResponse<null>> => {
      return requestor(Rest.sendRequest(param1, param2))
    },
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        // do something on success
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        // do something on error
      },
    },
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, but making this change results in this error:
`No overload matches this call.
   Overload 1 of 4, '(mutationFn: MutationFunction<unknown, params>, options?: Omit<UseMutationOptions<unknown, unknown, params, unknown>, "mutationFn">): UseMutationResult<...>', gave the following error.
     Argument of type '({ param1, param2 }: params) => AxiosResponse<null>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MutationFunction<unknown, params>'.
       Type 'AxiosResponse<null>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<unknown>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]`

Comment: I'm also trying to use the `error` on onError
`onError: (error) => {
        onError(error?.response?.data?.type)
      }`

but I get this other error message:
`Property 'response' does not exist on type 'unknown'`

Comment: I updated the snippet. ReturnType of the mutationFn needs to be a Promise.

Comment: Errors are always unknown: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-and-type-script#what-about-error
in the next major version, we'll default to `Error`.